# OpenCV find contours in a particular orientation

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to find a contour that is a gentle curve that should segment an image from one side to the other. There are interruptions to curve on the image for which I wish to interpolate.

Is there a way I can get OpenCV to:

- Favour contours in a particular direction - i.e. left-to-right in my image. (perhaps applying a filter beforehand may help?)
- Force contours to reach from the left boundary to the right boundary of my image.

Any tips or ideas would be much appreciated!

Thanks!
Chris.

Comment: Moments and morphological operations?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the strategy you'd use? I understand what these are, but I'm not sure what process you'd apply to get the desired result.

Comment: Could you upload an example input image and describe better your desired output (graphically)?